# Move all source data in a blend file to another folder

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

I have a .blend file with many movie strips, and movies inside meta strips, pointing to source files at say ***directory x***

1) Does Blender have a way to change all the references to ***directory x*** to ***directory y*** without having to go into each strip manually?

Comment: afaik there are "missing files" tools (report/find)  under file menu, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/file.html I don't know if it will work for you...

Comment: That worked, convert to answer and i'll accept your answer.

Comment: No, thanks, that was just a tip, to a manual section :) but you can also answer your own question, if you wish, to better describe your solution, maybe post some image, about how you did, etc for others to learn in future... good to know that it worked!